# how use strings with $ (not var) in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, string, variables

I place to the php line a large piece of html code with javascript inserts (with jQuery) in which $ symbols is present.

```
<?php
    $site = <<<SITE_CODE

                setTimeout(function(){$(g_utils._f().menu.current_id).trigger('click')}, g_utils.effects.animation(g_utils._f().animation.events.loading, 'delay2'));           

    SITE_CODE;

    echo $site;

?>
```

PHP takes this as a variable and produces an error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'
>   in D:\site\index.php on line 328

Tell me how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: you can do \$ to escape the character

Comment: Of course it takes it as a php-variable, it is inside the `<?php  ?>` tags without any quotes. Google for [php echo jquery](https://www.google.nl/search?q=php+echo+jquery) and you'll find what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you single quote the EOL string it will not evaluate any variable:

```
    $site = 

    <<<'SITE_CODE'

                setTimeout(function(){$(g_utils._f().menu.current_id).trigger('click')}, g_utils.effects.animation(g_utils._f().animation.events.loading, 'delay2'));           

    SITE_CODE;
```

Comment: Francisco Rodríguez, did not work, the problem persisted :(
if I delete strings with $ - everything works

Comment: Sorry, I though it was double quotes but it is single quotes, try it now.

Comment: Francisco Rodríguez!
Thank you! It's work!!!
And if now I still need to embed a php code (vartiables etc) in the php string - are there any ways? $$ for example, or something else?